# Cancel multiprocessing.Pool with SIGINT

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, python-multiprocessing

My goal is to compute several data points in parallel and write them to an IO device asynchronously. The data points cannot be written just by themselves but need to be wrapped; more precisely, I am writing a JSON array and the `[]` symbols around the structs are required.

My current approach is to use a `multiprocessing.Pool` and apply_async to compute the data points. Using a callback function, the data points are then send to a `multiprocessing.Queue` while a separate thread extracts elements from the queue synchronously and writes them to the IO device.

It may happen that I need to cancel the process with a SIGINT. In that case, I want the computation to finish safely, i.e. stop the computation of all `Pool` processes but finish writing all remaining elements in the queue and the `]` symbol.

So far, I did not manage to find a working solution for my problem.  At the current state, my two issues are:

- Sometimes, the process does not exit. The `SIGINT_handler` is called but the process doesn't terminate. I could not verify where this originates from but I assume it might be a deadlock in the queue? I wouldn't know how to prevent that though.
- As I understand it, `pool.terminate()` sends a SIGTERM to all its child processes. This apparently causes a KeyboardInterrupt exception in every one of them, cluttering the terminal with a dozen stack traces.

My code can be found below.

```
# Initialize the worker pool and necessary variables.
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
data_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
counter_lock = threading.Lock()
threads_todo = args.autnum

# This function is executed after each successful experiment.
def apply_finished(data):
    data_queue.put(data)
    with counter_lock:
        nonlocal threads_todo
        threads_todo -= 1

# Start the pool.
for i in range(args.autnum):
    pool.apply_async(collect_data, (args,), callback=apply_finished)
pool.close()

# This function is called if SIGINT is send to this process.
def SIGINT_handler(sig, frame):
    sys.stderr.write("SIGINT received. Cancelling...")
    sys.stderr.flush()
    pool.terminate()
    with counter_lock:
        nonlocal threads_todo
        threads_todo = 0
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, SIGINT_handler)

# Write the data to stdout until all workers terminate or a SIGINT is received.
sys.stdout.write("[\n")
while threads_todo > 0 or not data_queue.empty():
    try:
        data = data_queue.get(True, 1)
        s = data.decode('utf-8')
        sys.stdout.write(s)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except queue.Empty:
        data = None
sys.stdout.write("]")
```